# Fail to initialize IBM Blockchain Platform on VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, blockchain

Failed to activate extension: Failed to execute command "npm" with arguments "rebuild, grpc, --target=7.1.11, --runtime=electron, --update-binary, --fallback-to-build, --target_arch=x64, --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/electron" return code 1

Could not rebuild native dependencies Failed to execute command "npm" with arguments "rebuild, grpc, --target=7.1.11, --runtime=electron, --update-binary, --fallback-to-build, --target_arch=x64, --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/electron" return code 1. Please ensure that you have node and npm installed

PS C:\Users\k> code --version
1.44.2

PS C:\Users\k> node --version
v10.20.1

PS C:\Users\k> npm --version
6.14.4

I've installed all the dependencies and for some reason VS Code is failing to initialize.